# Python nameError help when importing from another file

Tags: python, maya

I have a function in maya that imports in other functions and creates a shelf with buttons for specific functions. I have a function that has a scriptJob command that works fine. if I import that file in manually and not through the shelf button, but gives a NameError when using the shelf script to run it.

This is an example of the script
myShelf.py file:

```
import loopingFunction
loopingFunction.runThis()
```

loopingFunction.py file:

```
import maya.cmds as mc
def setSettings():
    #have some settings set before running this
    runThis()

def runThis():
    print "yay this ran"
    evalDeferred(mc.scriptJob(ro=True,ac=["'someMesh.outMesh',runThis"])
```

if I run this through the shelf function, I get a `runThis nameError is not defined` and if I try modifying the scriptJob command to `loopingFunction.runThis`, I get a `nameError loopingFunction is not defined`(not sure if using `loopingFunction.runThis` is even correct, to be honest)

Not sure how I can get around this without having to manually import in the function rather than through the shelf file.

Answer (score 1):

Using string references for callback functions like this often leads to scope problems. (More on that, and why not to use strings, [here](https://theodox.github.io/2014/maya_callbacks_cheat_sheet))

If you pass the function directly to the callback as an object, instead of using a string, it should work correctly as along as you have actually imported the code.

in this case you want an evalDeferred -- do you actually need it? -- so it helps to add a little function around the actual code so that the scriptjob creation actually happens later -- otherwise it will get evaluated before the deferral is scheduled.

```
def runThis():
    print "callback ran"

def do_scriptjob():
    cmds.scriptJob(ro=True, ac=('someMesh.outMesh', runThis)

cmds.evalDeferred(do_scriptjob)
```

In both `runThis` and `do_scriptjob` I did not add the parens -- we are letting the evalDeferred and the scriptJob have the function *objects* to call when they are ready.  Using the parens would pass the *results* of the functions which is not what you want here.

Incidentally it looks like you're trying to create a new copy of the scriptJob inside the scriptJob itself.  It'd be better to just drop the `runOnce` flag and leave the scriptJob lying around -- if something in `runThis` actually affected the `someMesh.outMesh` attribute, your maya will go into an infinite loop.  I did not change the structure in my example, but I would not recommend writing this kind of self-replicating code if you can possibly avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem of nested/maya scope variables

```
mc.scriptJob(ro=True,ac=["'someMesh.outMesh',runThis"]
```

This line is a maya command string that is evaluated in the main maya scope (like a global)
As your function have a namespace with the import : 'loopingFunction', you need to enforce it in the string command.

```
import loopingFunction
loopingFunction.runThis()
```

You should write

```
evalDeferred(mc.scriptJob(ro=True,ac=["'someMesh.outMesh',loopingFunction.runThis"])
```

If you want something more general, you can do :

```
def runThis(ns=''):
    print "yay this ran"
    if ns != '':
        ns += '.'
    evalDeferred(mc.scriptJob(ro=True,ac=["'someMesh.outMesh',{}runThis".format(ns)])
```

and then run in shelf :

```
import loopingFunction
loopingFunction.runThis('loopingFunction')
```

like this you can write any formof namepsaces :

```
import loopingFunction as loopF
loopF.runThis('loopF')
```